# Склонение имен существительных

Tags: склонение, морфология

Ответьте, пожалуйста! Как употреблять правильно окончании : "ии, ий". Пример: "здании или зданий, инфекции или инфекций, компаний или компании ", правило одно для всех родов, если да, то какое, разъясните, в каких случаях они меняются, спасибо?!

Answer (score 1):

В случае со словами: "здании", "зданий". Это так: слово "здании" пишется, когда говориться об одном здании, а "зданий" - когда о нескольких. Например: "В этом здании находится ...", "Где-то среди этих зданий ...". А слово "информаций" первый раз вижу.

Comment: "инфекции или инфекций, компаний или компании"?

Comment: Всё зависит от того в каком числе употребляется слово: если во множественном, то "ий", а если в единственном, то "ии". Например: "В компании друзей."